# How to update ProgressBar with respect to downloaded data while downloading text data from web using Asynctask in android

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-progressbar

I want to show progressbar wrt to downloaded data from the web. Whether I have to create dynamically or have to reference by Id by creating it in xml.I am a little bit confused. Here is my code. Could you please tell me how?

```
package com.example.telugumovies;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
String category ="";
String[] cat = {"Upcoming","Telugu"};
private List<String> categories ;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    categories = new ArrayList<String>();
    int i=0;
    for(i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
        categories.add(cat[i]+" Movies");
    }
    ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter <String>(this, 
            R.layout.listview_rowlayout, R.id.tv, categories);

     // assign the list adapter
     setListAdapter(myAdapter);
}
 // when an item of the list is clicked
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView list, View view, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(list, view, position, id);
    Bundle giveCategory = new Bundle();
    if(position == 0)
    {
        try {
            new GetData().execute();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
        }
    }
    else if(position == 1)
    {
        giveCategory.putString("cate", cat[position]);
        Intent a = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Show_Years.class);
        a.putExtras(giveCategory);
        startActivity(a);   

    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sorry This option is not Available for Now ",
               Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    //String selectedItem = (String) getListView().getItemAtPosition(position);


}

class GetData extends AsyncTask<String,Integer,String>
{
    ProgressBar pb ;
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        pb = new ProgressBar(MainActivity.this);
        pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String alldata = "";
        int flag=1;
        String data = "";
          URL url = null;
          int i=0,j=0,count=0,c=0;
          URLConnection con = null;
          InputStream is = null;
          String line = null;
        try
        {
            url = new URL("http://www.filmibeat.com/telugu/upcoming-movies.html");
            con = url.openConnection();
            is = con.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
               //System.out.println(line);
                alldata = "";
                flag=0;
                if(line.contains("<h3"))
                {j=0;
                flag=1;
                    for(i=0;i<line.length();i++)
                {
                    if(line.charAt(i)=='<')
                    {
                        j=1;
                    }
                    else if(j==1 && line.charAt(i)=='>')
                    {
                        j=0;
                    }
                    else if(j==0)
                    {
                        alldata = alldata + (line.charAt(i));
                    }
                }
                }
                data=data+alldata;
                if(flag==1)
                {
                data=data+"$";
                }

        }
            System.out.println(data);
            return data;
        }
            catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            return data;
        }
        }
    protected void onPostExecute(String someting)
    {
        Bundle givedata = new Bundle();
        givedata.putString("moviedata",someting);
        Intent a = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Show_upcomingmovies.class);
        a.putExtras(givedata);
        pb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        startActivity(a);
    }
    }

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Using dynamically created progress bar or referencing it from an id, are both fine.

Using a reference from XML allows you to have more control on the progress bars appearance, as you would have designed it sepcifically for your need (like appearance, where it has to appear, etc..). But if that is not the case, you can use a dynamically created one as in your current code as well.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of ways. One is to define ProgressDiaolog as a field in your AsyncTask, then add it to your onPreExecuted():

```
pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
pDialog.setMessage("some downloading massage");
pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
pDialog.setMax(100); //you can adjust this
pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
pDialog.setCancelable(false);
pDialog.show();
```

Then you can update the progress by override updateProgress() in your AsyncTask and call pDialog.setProgress();

Comment: Hmm, he's asking about ProgressBar, not ProgressDialog.

Comment: Yes, you completely right, but it there is no a lot of difference. You can replace it in ProgressBar and add it to your layout (what he didn't do).